# How to handle CORS in Apache Wink?

Tags: http-headers, response, cors, access-control, apache-wink

How can I apply [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) in Apache Wink? What I basically need is adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to every response send from Wink (where we will replace the `*` for the allowed origins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be returning a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object. Using the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder` you can add headers to the response.

**Update:**

Another solution is to add a Servlet Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) on top of Wink that will add the headers to all responses.

Btw, in JAX-RS 2 it's possible to add Filters and Interceptors.

Comment: Yes but that would mean I have to add this header for every request I have (including a copy of every request which handles the OPTIONS request method). That is quite a lot of work and error prone. I tried to add a custom ResponseHandler to the chain, which works, but I couldn't figure out how to add a header for every response coming by.

Comment: Another solution is to add a javax.servlet.Filter on top of Wink that will add the headers to all responses.

Comment: Hey that should work I guess, I will give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but can be useful for future readers. Use the following code when you send the response back:

```
Response
            .status(200)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .entity(yourJsonResponse)
            .build();
```

Response is of type : `javax.ws.rs.core.Response;`